# Match using first part of regex if decimal exists and second part if none

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the leading zeros of a string to replace with an empty string. I can have a scenario with leading zeros such that there is a decimal: `0000000.005` or without: `000000000005`.

I've come up with: `/.+?(?=0\.)|.+?(?=[0-9]+)/`.

The first part matches all the leading zeroes up until I reach a `0.` pattern (i.e. `0000000.005` becomes `0.005`). The second part applies the same lazy, positive lookahead approach to leading zeros without a decimal (i.e. `000000000005` becomes `5`).

Since the second part (`.+?(?=[0-9]+)`) is stronger than the first, it will always turn `0000000.005` into `5`. Is there a way to, in one expression, only match using the first section if there is, say the presence of a decimal, and to use the other expression if not?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `replace(/^0+(?=0\.|[1-9])/, '')`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gmIU9p/1).

Comment: It seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a regex solution, you may use

```
s.replace(/^0+(?=0\.|[1-9])/, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gmIU9p/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `0+` - 1+ zeros
- `(?=0\.|[1-9])` - the next chars should be `0.` or a digit from `1` to `9`.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['000000000005', '0000000.005'];
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, '=>', s.replace(/^0+(?=0\.|[1-9])/, ''));
  console.log(s, '=>', Number(s)); // Non-regex way
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace()` fucntion in regex. 
Here is the demo code .

```js
var str = "00000000.00005";
var str1 = "0000000005";
if(str.includes(".")) //case 1
{
 str = str.replace(/0+\./g, '0.');
console.log("str ==>", str);
}
if(!str1.includes("."))//case 2 . 
{ 
  str1 = str1.replace(/0+\.|0+/g, '');
console.log("str 1 ===>", str1);

}
```